# csproj file in solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010

It's possible to set *.csproj file visible in Solution Explorer?
Now I use option "Open containing folder" on file from project and search *.csproj. How can I show it in SE?
 I use Visual Studio 2010 Premium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unload the project from solution. After that you can right click and select edit. There should be an extension somewhere that does this. Try PowerCommands. I believe it adds the conveniens button "Edit Project".

Answer (score 2):

Your *.csproj *is* the project(s) icons that show up below your solution root. You edit the .csproj right clicking the project icon in solution explorer and select properties. What else would you want?

Comment: I would like to open it as XML, sometimes I need it after merge code

Comment: You may also right click solution file and select "Open folder in windows explorer" to go to the folder containing the solution file if you want to edit or view the file directly.

Comment: Side note: When wanting to edit files after a merge I often take the old and new version of the file and open them in WinMerge, where I may move segments from one file to another.